# Does Christianity believe in reincarnation?

Tags: faith, comparative-religion, reincarnation

Most religions of the East believe in the transmigration of the soul from a dead body to a newborn body.

For example let us say a person called Dheeraj dies, then if immediately he is born into another body then we call this process of dying and taking birth as rebirth because before dying he was born and after dying he is again born.

Does Christianity believe in transmigration?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by rebirth? Do you mean being "born again of water and spirit", reincarnation, resurrection, or something else? I assume you mean reincarnation/transmigration, but it is best to clarify.

Comment: the broad answer is no because different denominations have different points of view

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because The asker has so formed his question as to require an answer requiring assent to a idea contrary to Christian teaching. Spiritual regeneration is contrary to Christianity as the Spirit though eternal is restricted to one individual, and the sins related to that individual human being.

Comment: @bye I don't think your reason to close this question as off topic is valid, the question doesn't require assent to an idea, you can very easily reject the notion and answer the question. It seems that you simply believe that the answer to the question is "no".

Comment: @freethinker36 you can ignore a lot of things, but that does not mean that they are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Christian Bible says you must be re born to enter heaven.  This is a spiritual rebirth through the acceptance of Christ in your heart.  Christianity does not believe in reincarnation.

Comment: Can you please add some source?

Comment: I am not sure this answer is universally correct. It is most likely true for the majority of Christian denominations both current and historical. However, I am fairly certain there historical traditions that teach a form of reincarnation. Modern ones may exist as well.

Comment: "he Christian Bible says you must be re born to enter heaven"—Factually true. "This is a spiritual rebirth through the acceptance of Christ in your heart"—Subjective interpretation of how one is "re born".

Comment: Your answer is misleading. I think you should rather state that most of Christianity doesn't believe in reincarnation because there are Christian Churches that do or did believe in reincarnation. The Cathars believed in reincarnation as do the Christian Gnostics.

Answer (score 0):

The words of Jesus have been recorded and he made it clear that there is a great gulf fixed, Luke 16:26, and none can pass from death back to the living. Jesus also made clear, Luke 12:20, that when a man dies, his soul is immediately required by God, without any delay.

Jesus also said that, at the end of time, all that are in the grave shall rise from the dead, John 5:28. And Jesus has promised, Matthew 16:27, that he shall come again, in the glory of his Father, with his angels; and then shall reward every man according to his works.

I thought I would make matters more clear if I quoted the words of Jesus Christ, himself, the Son of God.

Comment: This answer seems to be personal opinion. It would be improved by citing some sources to indicate that it represents the position of a Christian group (present or historical). It should also take into consideration that the idea that the Protestant Bible contains the entirely of Christian revelation and theology is not universal.

Comment: "You must be born again" At a superficial level this easily sounds like it could be talking about rebirth. So we need to consider the matter at far more than a superficial level. What do you think about verses other people see as referring to rebirth? Just because you don't see any doesn't mean no one else does.

Comment: This needs to quote the scriptural evidence for no physical rebirth. To my knowledge there is one clear passage: "It is given to man to die once, then the resurrection".

Comment: well, if you are reincarnating many times you are technically alive and just switching bodies and then maybe you truly die once and then the judgment.